# Linking to existing record on create with a many to many record

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a many to many relationship between two models (places and tags). However, there seems to be unnecessary duplication in the tags table.

For instance, when creating a new place with an exiting tag, it creates a duplicate tag with the same name and links it rather than linking the already existing tag.

I thought making the name field unique on the model would help but it understandably results in the following error when running a post request:

```
{"tags":[{"name":["tags with this name already exists."]},{"name":["tags with th
is name already exists."]}]}
```

**Serializer**

```
class PlaceTagSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ('name',)


class PlaceSerializerPost(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = PlaceTagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ('title', 'lat', 'lon', 'tags', 'featured_image_url', 'created_at')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data['tags']

        """
        Tags need to be deleted otherwise the place object will not save
        as they need to be handled separately.
        """
        del validated_data['tags']

        place = Place.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for tag_data in tags_data:
            place.tags.get_or_create(place=place, **tag_data)

        return place
```

**Model**

```
    class Tags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)


class Place(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    featured_image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
    live = models.BooleanField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `get_or_create` line. First of all, you're calling the method on the existing `place.tags.all()` QuerySet, and since you're creating a new place, this will never return an existing object.

Second, `get_or_create(defaults=None, **kwargs)` has two sets of arguments:

- `kwargs`: the values to search for, where you included `place` redundantly, since you were already filtering on `place.tags`. But essentially you're saying: find me existing `Tag` objects with the same `tag_data` and `place`.
- `defaults`: these attributes will be set for new objects, but won't be searched for. There's nothing to set here since `Tag` has only one field.

So in your case you should do:

```
tag, _ = Tag.objects.get_or_create(**tag_data)  
# I'm not sure what `tag_data` is, but it should be dictionary {'name': 'some tag name'}, if not:
tag, _ = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_data)
place.tags.add(tag)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help - that makes sense. However, I have the error "argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tags'" on the `place.tags.add(tag)` line. The format is also as you said: `{'name': 'some tag name'}`. The curl request I used was: `curl --request POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"title": "valuey", "lat":"1.1", "lon":"1.2", "featured_image_url":"http://example.com/test.jpg", "tags":[{"name":"one"}, {"name":"two"}] }' http://127.0.0.1:8000/places.json `

Comment: What also confuses me is that the tag object was succressfully created (also checked it in db) but it just seems that add method on the tag has something wrong with it. I've had a look through [django many to many documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) but nothing jumped out

Comment: Updated my response. `get_or_create()` returns a tuple (_obj_, _bool_)

Comment: That's great - works perfectly, thanks for your help